# what are differences between touchmove and gesturechange?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, webkit

I originally wanted to track one-finger panning on mobile webkit (iOS/Android). I found [Creating a "sticky" fixed-position item that works on iOS Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107722/detecting-real-time-scrolling-on-ios-safari) and I saw `gesturechange`.  But as far as I tried, `gesturechange` only seems to be fired for two-finger move.  Then I found `touchmove` event and it seems I can use that.

1. What are differences between `touchmove` and `gesturechange`?
2. Is it right to use `touchmove` for detecting one-finger panning?

Answer (score 4):

1.Touchmove, touchstart, touchend, touchcancel are part of the multi-touch sequence. A multi-touch sequence begins when a finger first touches the surface.

gesturechange, gesturestart, gestureend are still part of multi-touch sequence but they contain more precise objects. Not all devices support gesture events. They contain scaling and rotation information allowing gestures to be combined, if supported by the platform. If not supported, one gesture ends before another starts.

2.So if you are just aiming for one finger such as swipe or slider I would use just use the touchmove. Unless you really want to turn your swipe into a 3d effect or rotate it i would combine touchmove and gesturechange.

GL

source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW1