# How to listen or bind to scroll events in web app for iPhones (built in PhoneGap)?

Tags: jquery, ios, html, cordova

We have read conflicting information about whether it's advisable to bind to, or listen to, scroll events using jQuery.

Essentially, we want to animate in images whenever the user scrolls down the page, similar to what the Google Plus iPhone app does.

Is there a better way to respond to scroll events (specifically, when a hidden images comes into view and should be animated into visibility)? What have people done when binding to scroll events? Should we not use jQuery and roll something on our own?

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107722/detecting-real-time-scrolling-on-ios-safari

Comment: @ahren, could you post this as an answer? then i can award you the points.