# $(window).scroll not working correctly on mobile devices and internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I'm using jQuery-1.10.2 and I am using the function `$(window).scroll`. The `$(window).scroll` isn't being executed as I scroll on a mobile device, but rather when my finger releases the screen after scrolling. `$(window).scroll` is also delayed on IE10.

I use `$(window).scroll` to make a navbar scroll with the page by changing the css property `top:` on the `position:fixed;` navbar. When scrolled down for enough, the navbar ends up sticking to the top of the page as `position:fixed`. Is there a more compatible alternative to achieve the same results to my navbar? Is there a fix for mobile or IE10?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.navbar').css('top', Math.max(0, 350 - $(this).scrollTop()));
    var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
});
```

Here is a fiddle with no images. Look at the navbar. http://jsfiddle.net/93tzq/

Comment: try this `$(window).on('scroll mousewheel DOMMouseScroll touchmove',function(){...`

Comment: I couldn't test this on a mobile device but it didn't change the results of IE10. :\

Comment: The window.scroll event does not fire in MobileSafari (iOS) until it is done scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you want to do correctly I'm pretty sure you're over thinking this.To keep a nav element at top while you scroll you don't need any js. All you need to do is set the z-index and position accordingly.

For instance:

```
.nav-overlay{

position: absolute;
top: 90px;
left: 10%;
z-index: 100;
display: block;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
```

Then put the html as follow:

```
<nav class='nav-overlay'>
NAV BAR HERE
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your mobile browser, but this is a common question with Safari in iOS. MobileSafari does not trigger window.scroll until the scrolling has finished – this has been a problem addressed numerous ways (see [iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll), for example). Here's a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107722/detecting-real-time-scrolling-on-ios-safari) that may answer your question as far as making a sticky navbar.